# NSScrollView isFlipped question

Tags: objective-c, nsscrollview

If I am programmatically creating an NSScrollView how do I go about flipping it? For example:

```
//set up the page rect
displayPageRect=NSMakeRect(400.0, 40.0,pageWidth, pageHeight);
displayPage = [[NSScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:displayPageRect];
```

How do I then over ride the default isFlipped setting from NO to YES?

Tried [displayPage isFlipped: YES]; and got a warning that displayPage didn't recognize the method and then the app failed on run.

Comment: What are you trying to do? NSScrollView already returns YES from isFlipped. If you want your scroll view's document view to be flipped (which is totally reasonable), then simply override isFlipped in your view subclass and return YES.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can subclass NSView to take flipped view.

```
@interface FlippedView : NSView {
}
@end 

@implementation FlippedView
- (BOOL) isFlipped
{
    return YES;
}
@end
```

Than set your flipped view as documentView of NSScrollView.

```
NSScrollView *scrollView = [[NSScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
FlippedView *flippedView = [[FlippedView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[scrollView setDocumentView: flippedView];
```